# regex: reject the match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

python 3.5  re version 2.2.1

Toy example:

```
S1 = 'Arithmetic Return 2018 (%)'
s2 = 'Arithmetic Return 2019 (%)'

p = re.compile(r'(^.*?Arithm.*$)')
w = [re.findall(p, a) for a in [s1, s2]]
```

- How can I make sure that I will match only s2 that contains '2019'
- How can I ignore caps / lower case?

Comment: Your regex matches any line that has `Arithm` in it, see https://ideone.com/tejbbu. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is so specific about `s2` that you want to *only* match that text?

Comment: Is your regex supposed to be "any text that contains Arithm followed by 2019"?

Comment: the year....Essentially I want to match Arithm and NOT 2018. That is I want to reject 2018

Comment: It sounds as if you wanted to use `if 'arithm' in s.lower() and '2018' not in s:`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `2019.*` to your regex to match a string that contains `Arithm` (case insensitive through `(?i)`) 
followed by `2019` somewhere in the string. Like this: `(?i)^.*?Arithm.*2019.*$`.

I know it's not javascript but it's handy to see a working example, copied from regex101:

```js
const regex = /^.*?Arithm.*2019.*$/gmi;
const str = `Arithmetic Return 2018 (%)
Arithmetic Return 2019 (%)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

### Python:

```
import re

s1 = 'Arithmetic Return 2018 (%)'
s2 = 'Arithmetic Return 2019 (%)'

p = re.compile(r'(?i)^.*?Arithm.*2019.*$')
w = [re.findall(p, a) for a in [s1, s2]]
print(w)
```

Comment: well, python regexes aren't javascript regexes. In particular `//gm` don't exist in python

Comment: Anyway, it is not what OP needs. [*Essentially I want to match Arithm and NOT 2018*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308791/regex-reject-the-match#comment93498454_53308791) Nor does this answer *How can I ignore caps / lower case?*

Comment: No reason to use compile if you're not going to use the returned object. `w = [p.findall(a) for a in [s1, s2]]`